# Detect attached monitors when X is not running

Tags: rhel

I'm working with machines that are running RHEL6. I need to detect whether a monitor is plugged in when X is either not running or has not started yet, for example during bootup. Is there any way to do this? `lspci` shows video drivers and other hardware, for instance, but that's the closest I've been able to come so far to detecting monitors without going through X.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but would it be acceptable to depend on X being installed (though not starting all of it)? Maybe there's a tool in there somewhere that will help...

Comment: Apologies for taking a year and a half to answer, but yes, it is acceptable to use X tools/utilities even if the X server is not running.